# Restricting returned records with WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to pull data, but am having some difficulty getting my statement to work correctly. I believe the issue is within the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.id, 
                h.status, 
                a.billing_state, 
                d.queue_desc, 
                r.role_desc, 
                Datediff(day, recd_dt, Getdate() + 1) AS AGE, 
                h.drag_dt
FROM   dbo.tbl_1 h 
       JOIN dbo.prov p 
         ON h.id = p.id 
       JOIN dbo.address a 
         ON p.id = a.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.queue_msg m 
         ON h.id = m.msg_id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.queue_def d 
         ON m.queue_id = d.queue_id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.roles r 
         ON m.role_id = r.role_id 
       JOIN dbo.me_msg w 
         ON h.ck = w.ck 
WHERE  h.ck = '123' 
       AND a.type = 'PRI' 
       AND w.seq_no = '00000' 
       AND h.status IN ( '01', '02', '03' '04') 
       AND (( h.drag_dt BETWEEN '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                               '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000' 
             AND h.status = '04' ) 
              OR ( h.drag_dt BETWEEN '3334-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                                    '3334-12-31 00:00:00.000' 
                   AND h.status = '04' ) )
ORDER  BY 
h.drag_dt 
DESC
```

What I am trying to return;
- Records that are h.ck of 123
- Records that are a.type of PRI
- Records that are w.seq_no of 00000
- Records that are h.status of 01, 02, 03, or 04

Of the above returned records I want the following to ALSO be true';
- If the record has a h.drag_dt with a year of 9999, or 3334 then only return the ones with a h.status = 04
- If the record has a h.drag_dt with a year other than 9999, or 3334 then only return the ones with a h.status of 01, 02, or 03

Comment: This is probably an issue with your `AND` between `h.status IN (...)` and the two conditions where `h.status = '04'`. The status cannot be `IN ('01', '02', '03')` and also be `'04'` at the same time.

Comment: In addition to the above concerns depending on the datatype of drag_dt you may have another issue. if the date includes time and is on the last day of the date range your logic will miss it.

Comment: @MartinParkin I updated the h.status IN list to include 04.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you were almost there and I suspect this is what you are after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT --Does this need to be here?
       h.id,
       h.status,
       a.billing_state,
       d.queue_desc,
       r.role_desc,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, recd_dt, GETDATE() + 1) AS AGE,
       h.drag_dt
FROM dbo.tbl_1 h
     JOIN dbo.prov p ON h.id = p.id
     JOIN dbo.address a ON p.id = a.id
     LEFT JOIN dbo.queue_msg m ON h.id = m.msg_id
     LEFT JOIN dbo.queue_def d ON m.queue_id = d.queue_id
     LEFT JOIN dbo.roles r ON m.role_id = r.role_id
     JOIN dbo.me_msg w ON h.ck = w.ck
WHERE h.ck = '123'
  AND a.type = 'PRI'
  AND w.seq_no = '00000'
  AND (((h.drag_dt BETWEEN '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
      OR h.drag_dt BETWEEN '3334-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '3334-12-31 00:00:00.000')
    AND h.status = '04')
    OR (NOT (h.drag_dt BETWEEN '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
          OR h.drag_dt BETWEEN '3334-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '3334-12-31 00:00:00.000')
    AND h.status IN ('01', '02', '03')))
ORDER BY h.drag_dt DESC;
```